# Jsonp getting internal server error

Tags: error, ajax, json, magento1.9.2.3

I tried to update the order status using an external app file the process in Magento file execute successfully that I can update the order status but the issue in jsonp I get false function here is my index code (only ajax code showing)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery(".foot").hide();
jQuery("#shipstatus").hide();   
    jQuery(".btn").click(function(){ 
    var ordid = jQuery('#orderNum').val();
//alert(ordid); 
        var dataString = 'id='+ordid;
    alert(dataString);
        var response='';
        jQuery.ajax({

          type: "GET",
          async:false,
          url: "http://www.example.com/shippingstatus/index/updatestatus",
          data: dataString,
          timeout: 5000,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'foo', // for caching
          cache: true,
        success: function (parsed_json) {
        console.log(parsed_json);
},
           error: function() { jQuery(".foot").show();
           jQuery('.foot').text("Some error occured please try after some time"); }
      });
}); 
function foo(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }    
});

        </script>
```

> and my magento code to update status

```
<?php
namespace Aneka\ShippingStatus\Controller\Index;

class UpdateStatus extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    $orderId = $_GET['id'];
    /*$orderId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('ordnum');*/
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    $order->setState("complete")->setStatus("complete"); 
    $order->save();
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["uid"] = 10;
    echo json_encode($response);
    //exit;
  }
}
```

> error in console
>
> GET
>    http://www.example.com/shippingstatus/index/updatestatus?callback=foo&id=7567567567
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Dont use ObjectManager. it is not good coding standard. Try to inject Magento\Sales\Model\Order in your page

Comment: @Rama Chandran but i did't get any issue on there the order status change successfully my issue is i did't get the success response in ajax cal

Comment: Sure i will provide solution

Comment: I need you php errror log. it is mostly in /var/log/httpd/error_log.log file

Comment: @ Rama Chandran hey the issue resolved its some error in return data from php to ajax

Comment: Okey Great :). If any help please ask i always to help you :)

Comment: Please inject Magento\Sales\Model\Order in your __construct. that is good pratice

Comment: @ Rama Chandran 2 hours ago ok thank you will modify it

Comment: @Rama Chandran   can you answer the following question   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176915/checkout-page-custom-filed-value-not-save-in-magento-1-9-2