# Add a custom field in checkout and registration page in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: checkout, magento1.9.2.4, custom-field, registration

I need to add a custom field "Mobile" in registration and checkout pages.I have tried few methods but no luck. How can I achieve this?

> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mobilenum_Cusmobile>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Mobilenum_Cusmobile>
  </modules>
  <global>
       <fieldsets> 
     <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <customer_mobile_reg>
            <to_customer>mobile_reg</to_customer>
          </customer_mobile_reg>
     </checkout_onepage_quote>   
    <checkout_onepage_billing> 
        <mobile_reg> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </mobile_reg> 
    </checkout_onepage_billing> 
    <customer_account>
        <mobile_reg>
           <to_quote>customer_mobile_reg</to_quote>
         </mobile_reg>
     </customer_account>     
    <sales_convert_order>
        <customer_mobile_reg>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_mobile_reg>
    </sales_convert_order>  
</fieldsets>
        <helpers>
      <cusmobile>
        <class>Mobilenum_Cusmobile_Helper</class>
      </cusmobile>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <cusmobile>
        <class>Mobilenum_Cusmobile_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>cusmobile_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </cusmobile>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1486024557_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Mobilenum_Cusmobile</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_setup>
      <customerattribute1486024557_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_write>
      <customerattribute1486024557_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Mobilenum/Cusmobile/sql/customerattribute1486024557_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile_reg",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "mobile_reg");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Please refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14165/23825

Comment: @John I think this one is only for adding field in customer registration can you check this here is my full code https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176915/checkout-page-custom-filed-value-not-save-in-magento-1-9-2?noredirect=1#comment245131_176915

Comment: hi @amith here i have posted an answer for your question please try it and ask me if you have any querys. thanks

Comment: here i am showing you sample example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly follow the below steps:
I am posting the answer as per below considerations

1) module name: **Ewall_Test**  II) Attribute code: **custom_mobile**

**Step 1:** create a module using silk software with customer attribute (which i have posted first answer)

**Step 2:** `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

Keep the below code in the billing.phtml

```
<?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
<div class="field">
 <label for="billing:custom_mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Custom filed') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
     <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="billing[custom_mobile]" id="billing:custom_mobile" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCustomMobile()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Mobile Custom filed')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Step 3:** go to '**app/code/Ewall/Test/etc/config.xml**' of your module for customer attribute add below code inside the global tags

```
<fieldsets> 
     <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <customer_custom_mobile>
            <to_customer>custom_mobile</to_customer>
          </customer_custom_mobile>
     </checkout_onepage_quote>   
    <checkout_onepage_billing> 
        <custom_mobile> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </custom_mobile> 
    </checkout_onepage_billing> 
    <customer_account>
        <custom_mobile>
           <to_quote>customer_custom_mobile</to_quote>
         </custom_mobile>
     </customer_account>     
    <sales_convert_order>
        <customer_custom_mobile>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_custom_mobile>
    </sales_convert_order>  
</fieldsets>
```

**Screenshot:** [image]

**Step 4:** after adding the above code in the config.xml go to your database and find the table **sales_flat_quote** and then create a new column as shown below screenshot

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Step 5:**

**Clear cache & session** and go to checkout registration and do the process and check the same. thanks

Comment: i have added the xml code but the column was not added in sales flat quote table i don't know why it is

Comment: please take a screenshot of the error u r getting.

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA if you give me your email or skype id i can share the credential with you

Comment: please confirm whether u r getting this error http://prntscr.com/fjy6rp

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA ya im getting this error

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA Please see my updated question i have added the full code

Comment: the problem with the 'default' value of the 'update_at' column. so just change as shown this screenshot http://prntscr.com/fjyoz3   after changes has been done clear cache and session check the frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60497/discussion-between-amith-and-nagaraju-kasa).

Comment: Now its working thanks a lot... i made a mistake in database that's why its not working  thank you once again

Comment: Oh Good news @amith and please upvote for the answer so that it will help to other developers. thanks and have a good day. happy coding.

Comment: No idea @Amith....

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa can you answer for this i have an issue related this method in another project https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190385/custom-field-value-not-getting-saved-during-edit-the-value-in-magento-1-9

Comment: can you help me for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201931/configurable-not-adding-to-cart-in-magento2-1-9?noredirect=1#comment279795_201931

Comment: @NagarajuK I just the following link for adding extra column both frontend & backend & MySQL table => http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/ in the checkout page "area" column name not visible, but if i click to continue "Area" column validation work like please submit "Area" the fact is i can't able to see "area" column. Edit path => app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml script => https://justpaste.it/3t5rr Any help thanks.

Comment: i follow this but my new field attribute value not come in database sales_flat_quote table @NagarajuK

Answer (score 1):

**Note I:** Based on your question i have tried in default magento and got the solution.

Please follow the below steps and try the same in your local/default magento. Here i am showing you how to create a customer custom attribute and save the filed value while customer register from frontend.

**Step1:** Create a customer attribute using silk software tool.

[image: create a module for customer attribute]

Please specify the details as shown in the screenshot and download the module and install the module in your magento. don't forget to clear cache and session after installed the module.

**Note II:** Now login to admin and check the customer details you can able to view the new attribute text  field.

[image]
just check whether you are able to save and update the filed properly or not.

**Step2:** File path: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Keep the below code in the register.pthml

```
<label for="custom_mobile"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Custom Mobile Field') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="custom_mobile" id="custom_mobile" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCustomMobile()) ?>" 
title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Custom Mobile')) ?>" class="input-text" />
</div>
```

[image: keep the code as shown this screen shot]

**Note III:** if the field want to required you can specify the class required.

**Step 3:** Now click on register button and do the process as shown below screenshot.

[image: click on register]

**Step 4:** output screenshot here i am showing you.
[image: please check it admin end]

Comment: i have tried this before an i got this but my problem is i cant save the value using this on checkout registration how can i create this for both customer registration and checkout registration

Comment: My requirement is this i need a custom module mobile number which is used both in customer registration and checkout registration hear i make mobile as required filed and make telephone not required field. So i have to get the mobile number from customer from checkout registration ,Checkout as guest and customer registration how can i do this using this tool

Comment: Yes @amith i do understand your requirement. upto registration process i have posted answer, please confirm whether the above process has been worked or not?

Comment: yes its is working one i have already created the module you can see that code hear https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176915/checkout-page-custom-filed-value-not-save-in-magento-1-9-2

Comment: ok but while checkout registration process you are unable to save the value i am correct ? please confirm. thanks

Comment: yes thats the issue

Comment: amith i have tried and posted the new answer please check and get back i hope it will be workout. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60501/discussion-between-nagaraju-kasa-and-amith).

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA  How can i use this on shipping information i need to use this on customer address as like telephone

Comment: have you posted related question on this? plz share me link thanks

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181016/custom-field-value-not-showing-in-shipping-address-in-magento-backend/181018#181018

Comment: Did you see the question?

Comment: yes just now i saw

Comment: Do you have any solution