# custom field value not showing in shipping address in magento backend

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address, customer-address, custom-field

I have added a custom filed mobile number in magento 1.9 both in checkout and customer registration everything working fine if a customer register i can see the value in customer account information field but its not showing in customer address field which is used for shipping address

**My first requirement was need a custom field in registration page both checkout and customer registration so first i run this sql**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile_reg",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "mobile_reg");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer"; 
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();

$installer->addAttribute("customer_address", "mobile_reg",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer_address", "mobile_reg");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer_address";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_register_address";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_address_edit";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

After that we need to use the same field on shipping address also so separatly i run this following query

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer_address", "mobile_reg",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer_address", "mobile_reg");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer_address";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_register_address";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_address_edit";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**and my config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mobilenum_Cusmobile>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Mobilenum_Cusmobile>
  </modules>
  <admin>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_dataflow>
                <mobile_reg><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></mobile_reg>
            </customer_dataflow>
        </fieldsets>
    </admin>
  <global>
    <fieldsets> 
     <checkout_onepage_quote>
         <customer_mobile_reg>
            <to_customer>mobile_reg</to_customer>
          </customer_mobile_reg>
     </checkout_onepage_quote>   
    <checkout_onepage_billing> 
        <mobile_reg> 
            <to_customer>*</to_customer> 
        </mobile_reg> 
    </checkout_onepage_billing> 
    <customer_account>
        <mobile_reg>
           <to_quote>customer_mobile_reg</to_quote>
         </mobile_reg>
     </customer_account>     
    <sales_convert_order>
        <customer_mobile_reg>
          <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_mobile_reg>
    </sales_convert_order>  
</fieldsets>
<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <customer_mobile_reg><to_order>*</to_order></customer_mobile_reg>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <sales_convert_order>
                <customer_mobile_reg><to_quote>*</to_quote></customer_mobile_reg>
            </sales_convert_order>

            <sales_copy_order_billing_address>
                <mobile_reg><to_order>*</to_order></mobile_reg>
            </sales_copy_order_billing_address>

            <sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
            <mobile_reg><to_order>*</to_order></mobile_reg>
          </sales_copy_order_shipping_address>

          <sales_convert_quote_address>
            <mobile_reg><to_order_address>*</to_order_address><to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address></mobile_reg>
          </sales_convert_quote_address>

          <sales_convert_order_address>
            <mobile_reg><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></mobile_reg>
          </sales_convert_order_address>

          <customer_address>
            <mobile_reg><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></mobile_reg>
          </customer_address>

          <checkout_onepage_billing>
            <mobile_reg><to_customer>*</to_customer></mobile_reg>
          </checkout_onepage_billing>

          <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <mobile_reg><to_customer>*</to_customer></mobile_reg>
          </checkout_onepage_quote>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
      <cusmobile>
        <class>Mobilenum_Cusmobile_Helper</class>
      </cusmobile>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <cusmobile>
        <class>Mobilenum_Cusmobile_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>cusmobile_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </cusmobile>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1486024557_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Mobilenum_Cusmobile</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_setup>
      <customerattribute1486024557_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_write>
      <customerattribute1486024557_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1486024557_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi amith please clarify the http://prntscr.com/fp3sod so that i can assist u.

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA  Please check mu question added 2 screen shot

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA Now as we discussed before i got the custom field value in account information this can only getting through registration here i used mobile number insted of telephone in checkout form removing telephone from Required field and make mobile as required so if a user checkout as guest he will only fill the mobile number field that i need to get in back end with shipping address and billing address

Comment: Now Please confirm you would like to add a customer attribute field to customer address am i correct?

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA YA UR RIGHT But please note that i need this in shipping information for all type user if a user checkout as guest i need to show this on order details(in shipping and billing address)

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation please try the link might be which is sutible for your requirment http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/

Comment: Please confirm whether it is working or not.

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA I have tried this but the script(sql not running) we have already run the script for custom field i put this query on the same file. Do i need to create ew module for this by giving same attribute name

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA How can i use this code on my previous module which i used to crete field in customer registration and checkout registration form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61270/discussion-between-nagaraju-kasa-and-amith).

Comment: @ NAGARAJU KASA  can you try to answer for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181433/mutiple-website-with-multiple-sub-domain-in-magento-2

Comment: @NAGARAJU KASA  can you answer for this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186141/website-switching-in-magento-1-9-without-changing-the-default-url

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you added your mobile number attribute to customer entity which is wrong. You should add it as an attribute of customer address entity.

If I am wrong with my assessment, then please add more details to your question such as the attribute declaration code etc.

Comment: Please see my updated code