# Mutiple website with multiple sub domain in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3, base-url, multi-website

I'm trying to implement multiple website in Magento 2.1.3 For that, I have created an extra website store and store view

My site URL is like **www.example.com**

My subdomain is **www.kw.example.com**(where kw is the code of new website).

I have create sub domain in my domain and point this in to a new folder in Magento root folder which contain the index file of new website.
And i have changed the website URL and secure BASE URL as **www.kw.example.com** 
but when i try to access to this URL its redirecting in to **www.example.com**

Answer (score 2):

Follow this and comment for any issue:

1. Verify your desired domain name points to the server.
2. Create a secondary domain for your new store.
3. Using either FTP or SSH, copy the .htaccess and index.php files from your Magento installation to the document root of your new domain.
4. Open the index.php file that you just copied and edit the last lines of the file as follows:

**Attention**: Change newstore to the code that you wrote down when you created the new website above.

Replace:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

With:

`require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'newstore';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);`

5. Using SSH, create the following symbolic links in the document root of your new domain, and replace the path below with the full path to the document root of your Magento Installation:

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/pub/ pub

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var

**Update in Your case**:

Replace `ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app` with `ln -s /var/www/html/m2/example.com/app/ app`

Comment: I have followed this step but i dont have idea the step you mentioned in step 5 how can i do that

Comment: Thats important step. Do you have SSH access of site?

Comment: WIth SSH,  Go to root folder of  www.kw.example.com  and execute step [5].  "example/example.com/"  is your main domain here. This is where your main site is working.

Comment: My path to root is like this /var/www/html/m2/  so  imay run like this ln -s /var/www/html/m2/app/ app is it?

Comment: NO. Do one thing. Create a file: test1.php and upload this to root of your site. Put this code in file: <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Access this file from briwser: ie . example.com/test1.php. This will open details. Search for "$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']" . Here you will find the path. Comment that here

Comment: i got the same $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] /var/www/html/m2/info.php

Comment: Then replace "ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app" with ln -s "ln -s /var/www/html/m2/example.com/app/ app " and so on.   ---- P.S. example.com is your main site and you are executing CLI in RW root-folder

Comment: Updated the answer according to your case.

Comment: i think i have permission issue on app "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'app': Permission denied"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61344/discussion-between-jai-and-amith).

Comment: I have contacted with my server support tem regarding ghe permission issue and they saying "Document root of your parent domain name is /var/www/html/m2/  (/var/www/html/m2/example.com is not existing) . I think you need to remove domain name from the directory path to create this.  "

Comment: Which  hosting company you are using? and Say them that SSH user need permission of write to root folder.

Comment: i run the code like this and no error found "/var/www/html/m2/Kuwait$ ln -s /var/www/html/m2/example.com/app/ app"  where Kuwait is my new root folder which is pointing the subdomain placed inside root folder og magento but after doing this also sub domain redirecting to main domain

Answer (score 0):

Here is example you could setup:

your M2 site root folder:

> /var/www/m2

your domains:

```
v1.example.com
v2.example.com
```

- create 2 websites (website codes: sitev1 and sitev2)
- update website domains under **System** > **Configuration** > **Web**.
- update virtual hosts on your server and setup environment variables.

Example for apache

```
SetEnvIf Host .*v1.example.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=sitev1
SetEnvIf Host .*v1.example.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host .*v2.example.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=sitev2
SetEnvIf Host .*v2.example.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Notice: if you have PHP running in CGI mode on your server you will need to update index.php with this line:

```
/* Load Stores via SERVER REDIRECT_ */
$params = $_SERVER;
if (isset($params['REDIRECT_' . \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE])) {
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $params['REDIRECT_' . \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE];
}
if (isset($params['REDIRECT_' . \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE])) {
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $params['REDIRECT_' . \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE];
}
/* END */

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```